# How to reload AngularJS page each time through javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Below is the code in my AngularJs controller,

```
var app=angular.module('single-page-app',['ngRoute']);
app.config(function($routeProvider){
     $routeProvider

      // Home
   .when("/", {templateUrl: "p", controller: "PageCtrl"})
   // Pages
   .when("/q", {templateUrl: "q", controller: "qcontrol"}));
});

app.controller('qcontrol',function($route){
$route.reload();
});
```

Here is the code that I use to redirect to other age, code works fine for first time however, page reload is not happening depeding on the ajax call.

```
var setOtherUserid="MFriends?oid=" + tmpArry[0] + "&fName=" + tmpArry[3] + "&lName=" + tmpArry[4];
$.get(setOtherUserid,function(data){
window.location = "#/Mf";

//window.location.reload();

});
```

How can I achive this, the page should be reloaded everytime when select to see that page.

I had tried using $route.reload(), window,location.reload().. etc but no luck.

Please help me

Comment: Am not seeing `#/Mf` in the routes you have mentioned

Comment: what is the goal here? this is definitely an XY Problem.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378.   A few things... Angular is designed to NOT reload inherently; You seem to be mixing Angular with JQuery which is usually bad outside directives; and you don't have a route matching the URL you are trying to set.  It seems like you might want to explain a bit more about what you are trying to do, and decide if angular is even the right tool for the job here.

Comment: code will go into infinite loop when you call `/q` as you did `$route.reload();` on controller init `qcontrol`

Comment: in fact, it seems that this is related to the other question you asked, where you accepted an answer telling you that **you shouldn't** be trying to reload, only to ask again how to do it.  I strongly encourage you to make an attempt to explain what you have in more detail; perhaps you aren't "thinking in angular"....

Comment: @monicaMishra she should explain more what exactly you want here, and I saw your code it use `$.get` which is jquery ajax..you shouldn't use that because it will never run digest cycle of angular in anyway after ajax completion